# Declare a List of class references

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I need to declare a list of class references. Specifically, a list of classes which implement a interface which here I'll call `IInterface`.

Similar to how List can be a list of types and look like this:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type> {string, bool, int, float};
```

I need to accomplish the same thing, where each of those are my own classes and implement the interface IInterface so:

```
List<(idk)> references = new List<(idk)> {myClass, myClass2, myClass3};
```

and all of them are `MyClass : IInterface`, `MyClass2 : IInterface` and `MyClass3 : IInterface`.

I need this so that when I create and instance of the type, the compiler will know that the type implements `IInterface`.

Comment: Are you trying to add types to this list or instances of those types?

Comment: Yeah this is unclear, if you want to add instances, `List<IInterface>` is fine, or are you trying to create a list of `Type` limiting it to your own types with some sort of compile time checking?

Comment: @maccettura That was the first I thought, but it seems like they want a `List<Type>` instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto oh I misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want basically a `List<Type>` where the `Type`s are required to implement an interface and you want this to be enforced at compile time, this is actually possible by wrapping `List<Type>` and making the add method have a constrained generic type parameter and using that to add to the list, but it may be a bit clumsy to use (you won’t be able to use the nice collection initializer syntax you allude to in your question):

```
public class TypeList<T> : IEnumerable<Type>
{
    private List<Type> _list = new List<Type>();

    public void Add<TAdd>() where TAdd : T
    {
        _list.Add(typeof(TAdd));
    }

    public IEnumerator<Type> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The generic type parameter for this class is the type you want the list constrained to, so in your example, using the list would look like:

```
var list = new TypeList<IInterface>();
list.Add<MyClass>();
list.Add<MyClass2>();
list.Add<MyClass3>();
```

And these would fail to compile:

```
list.Add<string>();
list.Add<bool>();
list.Add<int>();
list.Add<float>();
```

Comment: I was thinking I'd end up having to create my own Class to do this, but, yeah this works

Answer (score 1):

You're just after a `List<Type>` here with `TypeOf(myClass), TypeOf(myClass2)...` as values. You'd have to do an additional check if you want to actually verify that these types implement `IInterface`. You can't specify at compile time that the types should only be ones that implement your interface.

As as aside this sounds like prerequisite to Dependency injection, you might want to take at Microsofts Unity dependency injection framework if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

> I need this so that when I create and instance of the type, the compiler will know that the type implements IInterface.

Below I'm showing you two possible ways to get List of `type` of those classes which are implementing `IInterface`. So while creating new object, you can use this list to decide whether this class is implementing `IInterfce` or not.

- **Compile Time Solution**

If you want a compile time solution, you should have a `List<IInterface>` , then only those classes' object will be allowed in this list which implement `IInterface`. After having this list (which have only those classes' object which implements `IInterface` use this list to prepare List of type.

For Ex.

class `Demo` implements an `IInterface` and `Demo2` doesn't.

```
    List<IInterface> listOfIInterface = new List<IInterface>();
    listOfIInterface.Add(new Demo());
    listOfIInterface.Add(new Demo2()); //this line will have compile time error
```

now use this list to prepare type's list

```
    List<Type> listOfIInterfaceType = new List<Type>();
    foreach(object obj in listOfIInterface)
    {
        listOfIInterfaceType.Add(obj.GetType());
    }
```

- **Run time Solution**

If you want more dynamic and run time solution for your problem, try this.

If there are multiple classes and you want to know which class implements `IInterface` and pick those class's type into a list. you can try following code.

Suppose, there are two classes `Demo` and `Demo2`. `Demo` does implement an `IInterface` while `Demo2` doesn't.

at you have object of both class, you put them into List of `Object` and loop on this list and perform following logic.

```
    List<object> listOfObject = new List<object>();
    listOfObject.Add(new Demo()); //Demo Implements IInterface
    listOfObject.Add(new Demo2());//Demo2 doesn't Implement IInterface

    //this will have all possible types
    List<Type> listOfAllType = new List<Type>();
    //this will have type of those class, which implement interface
    List<Type> listOfInterfaceType = new List<Type>();
    //this will have objet of those class, which implement interface.
    List<object> listOfInterfaceObject = new List<object>();

    foreach (object obj in listOfObject)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        if (!listOfAllType.Contains(type))
            listOfAllType.Add(obj.GetType());

        IInterface testInstance = obj as IInterface;
        if (testInstance != null)
        {
            if (!listOfInterfaceType.Contains(type))
                listOfInterfaceType.Add(type);
            if (!listOfInterfaceObject.Contains(obj))
                listOfInterfaceObject.Add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Note that if any class is not implementing an interface, it's object cannot be cast into Interface. So if `testInstance` is still null after trying to cast, It's class is not implementing the interface.

Comment: You don't need the try-catch if you use `obj as IInterface` and check for null instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks.. I have updated code accordingly